# Prove $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_N (x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} \lim_{N\to\infty} f_N(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_N $ is a function sequence that is integrable on $(a; b)$ for all $N $ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} f_N (x)$ exists for all $x$ in $(a; b) $

Does the following necessarily hold?:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_N (x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} \lim_{N\to\infty} f_N(x) dx$$

Comment: Not necessarily , consider the sequence $f_n(x)=n , 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $f_n(x)=0 $ for $\frac{1}{n}<x\leq 1$.

Comment: Is the integral Lebesgue?

Comment: It may be helpful to look up- 'Dominated convergence theorem'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no.

Take the function

$$f_N(x)=\begin{cases}N&\text{ if } 0<x<\frac1N\\ 0&\text{ if } x\geq \frac1N\text{ or } x=0\end{cases}$$

on $[0,1]$ as a counterexample.

Then, $$\int_0^1 f_N(x)dx = 1$$
for all $N$ and $$\lim_{N\to\infty} f_N(x) = 0$$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is correct only if the functions $f_N(x)$ tend to $f(x)$ uniformly.

Proof: Let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. Uniform convergence implies that:$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad,\quad \exists N\quad,\quad\forall x\in(a,b), n>N\quad,\quad |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$which leads to $$f(x)-\epsilon<f_n(x)<f(x)+\epsilon$$since both $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ are integrable we can argue that:$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)-\epsilon dx<\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx<\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+\epsilon dx$$or$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx-(b-a)\epsilon <\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx<\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx+(b-a)\epsilon$$which means that$$|\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx|<(b-a)\epsilon$$and implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx$$

Comment: "The statement is correct only if the functions $f_N(x)$ tend to $f(x)$ uniformly." That's not true.

Comment: Why not? give a counterexample with uniform convergence....

Comment: Take $f_n(x)=x^n,\ 0\leq x<1$. Then $\int f_n\to0$ but $f_n$ doesn’t converge uniformly to $0$.

Comment: Nope! $f_n(x)=x^n$ doesn't converge uniformly. Also refer to "Real
Mathematical Analysis" by Charles C. Pugh Chapter 4. This has been exemplified there...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I'm sorry you can't understand why what you wrote is incorrect. Perhaps it's a language problem.